# Making a program where you click as many times you can in a set time and stop the program and break the program after time is up

Tags: python

So I have an assignment to make a program where I make a clicks per 20 second game in python while also implementing a timer to start when the program starts and break the program after the 20 seconds is up.

I tried to first use time sleep which didn't work simultaneously with the clicking game so now I'm onto time.time() with a while statement.  I made the timer and put the game code under the while statement but the timer doesn't work.

```
from graphics import *
import time

start = time.time()
end = start + 20 #20 second timer

while time.time() < end:
    def display(x,y):
        global numClicks
        clear()
        numClicks +=1
        drawString("Number of clicks: "+str(numClicks),
    100,150,"Arial",28,"normal")
        update()

    numClicks = 0
    beginGrfx(800,500)
    onscreenclick(display)
    endGrfx
```

The clicking game worked at first too but now after 1 click it breaks along with the timer not working.

the error i get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\4th HOUR PROGRAMMING B SPRING 2019\PYTHON\click\click.py", line 17, in <module>
    beginGrfx(800,500)
  File "H:\4th HOUR PROGRAMMING B SPRING 2019\PYTHON\click\graphics.py", line 91, in beginGrfx
    tracer(0,0)
  File "<string>", line 5, in tracer
turtle.Terminator
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to handle this is to make a timer on a new thread (via the [`threading` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects)), and have it disable clicking when it goes off. For example:

```
import threading

canClick = True

def disableClicking():
    global canClick
    canClick = False

timer = threading.Timer(20.0, disableClicking)
timer.start()

while canClick:
    # the rest of your code for counting clicks
```

After 20 seconds, the timer will go off, `canClick` will be set to false, and the loop will end.